# Solution to two-dimensional PDE (wave/Klein-Gordon type equation)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics, wave-equation

I was playing with an optimization problem and ended up reducing it to solving the following PDE:
$$ a^2 xy \frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial x \partial y} + f = -axy(y+2ax) $$
where $a \in \mathbb{R}^+$ is fixed and $f : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ is unknown. I have no experience whatsoever with PDEs, but noticed I could separate $x$ and $y$ by changing variables $t = (x+y)/2$ and $r = (x-y)/2$, giving
$$ \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 t} - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 r} + \frac{4}{a^2(t^2-r^2)} \right) f = g(t,r) $$
for some fixed $g$ (not relevant here). This looks something like the 1+1-dimensional (time + 1D) [Klein-Gordon equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klein%E2%80%93Gordon_equation)
$$ \left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 t} - \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 r} + m^2 \right) f = 0 $$
except for the rightmost term in the bracket and the RHS of the equation, which both vary with $t,r$ in my case. It also looks a little bit like [the inohomogeneous Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation#Inhomogeneous_Helmholtz_equation) or the [screened Poisson equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screened_Poisson_equation) depending on whether $xy > 0$ or $xy < 0$, except they also have a constant rightmost term in the bracket AND have no time-component. I have no idea where to start, having no expertise in PDEs. I tried looking at [the](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1411.6988.pdf) [following](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1140/epjc/s10052-020-7781-5.pdf) [papers](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/2399-6528/ab42c6/pdf) but had a hard time following. Any guidance, hints, solutions most appreciated.

Comment: Crossposted to https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/673070/2451

Comment: As you provided no conditions at the far field, and the RHS is a polynomial, it makes sense to make an ansatz of the form $f = \alpha_{1} x^{2} y + \alpha_{2} x y^{2}$. Substituting into the PDE

\begin{align}
a^{2} xy (2 \alpha_{1} x + 2 \alpha_{2} y) + \alpha_{1} x^{2} y + \alpha_{2} x y^{2} &= (1+a^{2}) \alpha_{1} x^{2} y + (1+a^{2}) \alpha_{2} x y^{2} \\
&= -a x y^{2} - 2a^{2} x^{2} y
\end{align}

so a solution exists with $f$ defined above where $\alpha_{2} = -a/(1+a^{2})$ and $\alpha_{1} = -2a^{2}/(1+a^{2})$.

Comment: @mattos Amazing. 1) How did you make this ansatz? I can see why it would take this form - but how do you know when polynomial ansatz are something to try in the first place? 2) Is this the unique solution?

Comment: I made this guess because the inhomogeneity on the RHS is a polynomial. Note that the solution I gave is the _particular_ solution $f^{p}$; there also exists a _homogeneous_ solution $f^{h}$ that solves $$axy f^{h}_{xy} + f^{h} = 0$$ which I haven't provided. Note also that your PDE is singular when $x = 0$ or $y = 0$. We need information on the boundary conditions in order to help determine if a solution is unique, but you haven't provided this, so there is no way of knowing at this point.

Comment: @mattos 1) Thanks for the details - would you like to write your comment as an answer so I can accept it (and provide also the homogeneous solution if you don't mind)? 2) I assume the homogeneous solution can be added up to any scalar to the particular solution, so the solution is definitely not unique? 3) The only boundary condition I can provide is that $f \to \mp\infty$ as $x \to \pm\infty$ (independently of $y$, unless $y=0$ in which case $f=0$).

Comment: About the homogeneous solution: changing co-ordinates $x=\chi+i \eta$, $y=\chi-i \eta$ yields $r^2 \nabla^2 f +f =0$ in polar $\chi, \eta$ co-ords. Probably there is simpler way...

Comment: @Sal Thanks - but how does it help to find the homogeneous solution?

Comment: It helps because the transformed equation may be solved using [separation of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_variables#Partial_differential_equations) ie. letting $f(r,\theta)=R(r)\Theta(\theta)$

Comment: @Sal Thanks, I followed through and got solutions to the homogeneous case. My only concern is: how can we change to complex variables $\chi\pm i\eta$ given that $f$ is only defined on real numbers? My final solutions for $f$ involve $i \in \mathbb{C}$ and it's not obvious to me whether they reduce to real-valued functions.

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, thank you - also looking at that right now!

Comment: Yes, that substitution is much nicer!

Comment: @Sal Is it though (the substitution on the physics SE crosspost)? It doesn't seem to lead to a solution using separation of variables. Also, I'm still concerned about the change to complex variables. Does it make sense given $f$ is defined on real numbers a priori?

Comment: @mattos Would you like to write your comment into an answer so I can accept it?